# python %precision magic function does not work for print()

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

```
%precision 2
    x = 2/3
    print(x)
```

this prints

```
0.6666666666666666
```

instead of

```
0.67
```

any idea why it does not work?
I'm using ipython notebook
Thanks

Comment: somehow the three lines code does not show up correctly, hope a moderator fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%precision` isn't supposed to affect `print`. I don't think IPython actually does anything to modify the behavior of the `print` function. `%precision` is only intended to affect IPython's own pretty-printing, like what you get if you type an expression into the prompt without calling `print` on it.

Comment: thanks, hope there is a simple way to do it for print() function also, I do not want to put format statements to all the print functions